# Mapping UrlEncoded POST Values in ASPNET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a POST action within an Web API controller. The header received is...

```
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 19094
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.uk
```

In my IIS logs I can see the GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY as

```
"This is some posted data"
```

However I do not seem able to grab this piece of data using my web api controller.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string value)
```

The data being sent does not seem to fit the format required.  From my understanding Microsoft decided that anything posted to the FromBody attribute needs to be prefixed with "=" e.g.

```
="This is some posted data"
```

However the data I am receiving (from a source I have no control over) does not contain the "=".

```
"This is some posted data"
```

My web api method therefore completely ignores the data sent in.  I have tried to switch to using a FormDataCollection but as the data I am receiving does not have a key specified the value seems to end up in the key field which seems a bit odd.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(FormDataCollection form)
{
    string extracted = form.ReadAsNameValueCollection().GetKey(0);
}
```

I have tried making a class/complex type to wrap this but as the data posted doesn't contain a key it never seems to match up.

Am I missing something obvious.  I simply want to get the piece of data posted to my web service as a string?  Any help appreciated.

### UPDATE

After much searching I found a few people with the same issue and it appears they have had to move up the stack a bit and use the HttpRequestMessage.  Obviously not ideal as it makes unit testing a bit of a nightmare.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    string extracted = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

If anyone has a nicer way to accomplish this then please let me know.

Comment: Not a nicer way, but a remark. Don't use `Result` as this leads to blocking code; Use async/await properly.

Comment: Many thanks for the heads up, amazing what slips past you with a bit of copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Handling POST in WebApi [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/16/Mapping-UrlEncoded-POST-Values-in-ASPNET-Web-API)

```
 public class LoginData
 {
     public string Username { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
 }

 [HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(LoginData login)
{
string username = login.Username;
string password = login.Password;
…
}
```

Comment: Many thanks but for that to work the posted content needs to supply a parameter name (username or password) which the data does not specify.